# find() on new created element not work

Tags: jquery

I create new jQuery element:

```
var myJqEl = $('<div id="myDiv">Div content<span>Span content</span></div><p>P content</p>');
```

then I use find method on it:

```
var mynewEl1 = myJqEl.find('div').html(); // return null
var mynewEl2 = myJqEl.find('span').html(); // return Span content
var mynewEl3 = myJqEl.find('p').html(); // return null
```

Could you tell me why the first and the third return null while the second return the full content?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you're searching for a `DIV` that' is the jQuery object you're using to search on. There is no `DIV`, or `P`, in that `DIV`.

Comment: See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BG2FG/ What's the first line log?

Comment: can you post all of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` for the `div` and `p` instead:

```
var mynewEl1 = myJqEl.filter('div').html();
var mynewEl2 = myJqEl.find('span').html();
var mynewEl3 = myJqEl.filter('p').html();​
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap all your HTML content into another element, for example a `div` one. So this code:

```
var myJqEl = $('<div><div id="myDiv">Div content<span>Span content</span></div><p>P content</p></div>');
```

So you will have the correct element that you want and you can use `find` method on it.

**For more explanation:**

When you create new elements with `$`, jQuery will create an object that we called it `Wrapped Set`. This wrapped set is actually a javascript array, so when you create something like this:

```
$('<div id="myDiv">Div content<span>Span content</span></div><p>P content</p>');
```

You have an array with two objects: the first one, your `div` and the second one, the `p`. In the google chrome Web Inspector, you will see something like this:

```
[<div id=​"myDiv">​…​</div>​, <p>​P content​</p>​]
```

When you use a method like `find` in your wrapped set, it will be execute on the first element, the `div` tag in this example.

This is the reason why your `mynewEl2` return the correct data. Because the `span` tag is exists in the `div` (first element in your wrapped set)
The `div` tag doesn't have any `div` tag in itself. So `mynewEl1` is empty.

And when you wrap all your HTML data into single tag, your wrapped set contains only one element and all your HTML data will exists there.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different elements in the root level, if you had a "root" containing those 2 elements the first and the third lines wouldn't retrieve `null`.

For instance, try defining your variable `myJqEl` like this:

```
var myJqEl = $('<div><div id="myDiv">Div content<span>Span content</span></div><p>P content</p></div>');
```